# Little-Parks effect, Superconductors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, superconductivity

So I do generally understand the derivation of the [Little-Parks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%E2%80%93Parks_effect) effect but I do not know how it can be measured. Since the critical temperature oscillates with a period of $$T=(\phi/\phi_{0}),$$ $\phi$ being the magnet flux and $\phi_{0}$ the fluxquantum.

$T$ always being an integer since $\phi_{0}$ is the smallest possible flux, one should not be able to measure the oscillation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that $\phi_0$ is the smallest flux. For a thick walled cylinder (thick compared to the penetration depth, so that there is is a closed path in the superconducting materialalong which  the screening current vanishes) the flux through the core has to be an integer multiple of $\phi_0$, but for a thin walled cylinder the flux $\phi$ can  as small as one likes.